# ¿Por qué la pregunta "Cálculo del n-ésimo número armónico" sigue teniendo tantos votos en contra?

Tags: discusión

Tuve curiosidad de ver cuáles eran las preguntas que tenían más votos en contra. Por lo general son preguntas muy malas y llegué incluso a votar la eliminación de algunas de ellas.

Sin embargo vi una pregunta que, por los comentarios se ve que era muy mala al principio, pero luego el OP la mejoró, sin embargo, sigue teniendo muchos votos negativos.

La pregunta en cuestión es la siguiente: **[Cálculo del n-ésimo número armónico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/29215/29967)**.

Cabe decir que la misma tiene una [respuesta excelente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/63627/29967) dada por @PaulVargas.

¿Hay alguna manera de advertir a quienes votaron en contra que reconsideren ese voto?

¿Ven alguna posible salida a situaciones como esta?

Comment: La [página de reputación del OP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/19792/marxal?tab=reputation) muestra 7 votos negativos entre que pregunto (17.43) y editó añadiendo código (18.40), como se ve en la [página de revisiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/29215/revisions). A partir de allí, [su línea de tiempo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/29215/timeline) muestra que le han ido cayendo votos negativos algo así como _por inercia_ (alguien ve algo votado negativamente y zas, hace lo mismo pese a que teóricamente ya no lo merezca).

Comment: Hasta donde sé, no hay manera de saber quién voto o notificarles (la única manera sería si ellos marcaron la pregunta como favorita para seguimiento).

Comment: Otra cosa a valorar es ¿cuál es la pregunta en esa publicación? Porque lo que OP pregunta no es "_No sé como hacer X, ¿cómo se haría?_", lo que realmente se pregunta es "_He hecho este ejercicio, ¿alguien me lo puede corregir/mejorar?_" y en ese punto es debatible si incluso es una pregunta pertinente al sitio (porque no hay ningún problema real que resolver).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, pero dado que al menos una respuesta dada es buena y y tiene buena aceptación, ¿se debería perder dicha respuesta porque la pregunta no está bien planteada, o no sería mejor tratar de guardarla, instando al OP a mejorar lo que hiciera falta?

Comment: La respuesta no se va a perder porque nadie está diciendo de borrar la pregunta (y las preguntas con respuestas positivas no se eliminan automáticamente, siendo ésta un buen ejemplo de ello). Lo que digo es que puede darse el caso de que haya una respuesta excelente en una pregunta mala (por eso existe la medalla [Reversión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal)), y esta pregunta en particular está en una zona gris donde muchos usuarios pueden considerarla no buena por su contenido.

Comment: Aparte de eso (que es un caso particular), creo que la propuesta de esta pregunta es muy buena. Es uno de los motivos por los que no voto negativo muy a menudo y si se encontrara un método bueno, sería el primero en utilizarlo.

Comment: No me parece una buena pregunta. Que el problema de fondo sea interesante no la convierte en buena.. Posible salida a situaciones como esta: 1. editar, y editar mucho, para que quede más que claro el estado del código con el que intentó, si funciona y busca el método más eficiente, o no funciona y dónde falla. 2. ofrecé una recompensa, y aclará en el mensaje de la misma que la pregunta es interesante/buena/no tan mala. 3. compartí el enlace en foros que hablen de números armónicos, twitteala y compartila por facebook. Con eso vas a lograr muchísimo más que el efecto meta que logres acá.